# Give discount based on subscribed year

Tags: oracle, if-statement, for-loop, plsql, oracle9i

Table : SUBSCRIPTION

```
C_ID    SUB_YEAR    SUB_AMOUNT  DISCOUNT  PAID_AMOUNT
----------------------------------------------------
1      1            1250          0       0
2      2            2520          0       0
3      8            1459          0       0
4      6            7456          0       0
5      1            2584          0       0
6      3            2578          0       0
7      4            5478          0       0
8      5            5000          0       0
```

The query i need is,

- if sub_year is > 2 then he/she get 10% discount
- and sub_year>2 or <=3 then he/she get 20% discount
- and sub_year>3 then get 25% discount.

After running the query the discount and paid_amount column should be populated by values.

My query is :

```
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN(SELECT  SUB_YEAR FROM SUBSCRIPTION)
    LOOP                                                                                  
        IF(REC.SUB_YEAR>1 AND REC.SUB_YEAR<=2) THEN
            UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION
            SET DISCOUNT = 10,P_AMOUNT= SUB_AMOUNT-SUB_AMOUNT*.1;
        ELSIF(REC.SUB_YEAR>2 AND REC.SUB_YEAR<=3) THEN
            UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION
            SET DISCOUNT = 20,P_AMOUNT= SUB_AMOUNT-SUB_AMOUNT*.2;
        ELSIF(REC.SUB_YEAR>3) THEN
            UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION
            SET DISCOUNT = 25,P_AMOUNT= SUB_AMOUNT-SUB_AMOUNT*.25;
        ELSE
            UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION
            SET DISCOUNT = 0,P_AMOUNT= SUB_AMOUNT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
        Dbms_output.put_line('No Employee Selected');
    ElsIF SQl%FOUND THEN
        Dbms_output.put_line('Employee Selected');

    END IF;
END;
```

The problem is for all rows, the `discount` column is populated with 25% and `paid_amount` with 25% discount of sub_amount.

Comment: what is the data_type of the SUB_YEAR column in your SUBSCRIPTION table

Comment: c_id number,sub_year integer,sub_amount integer, discount integer, p_amount integer. sub_year is total count of years.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed a `WHERE` clause in your query,

```
BEGIN
     FOR REC IN(SELECT SUB_YEAR FROM SUBSCRIPTION)
     LOOP                                                                                  
          IF(REC.SUB_YEAR>1 AND REC.SUB_YEAR<=2) THEN
               UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION
               SET DISCOUNT = 10,p_amount= SUB_AMOUNT-SUB_AMOUNT*.1
               WHERE sub_year >1 and sub_year <= 2
          ELSIF(REC.SUB_YEAR>2 AND REC.SUB_YEAR<=3) THEN
               UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION
               SET DISCOUNT = 20,p_amount= SUB_AMOUNT-SUB_AMOUNT*.2
               WHERE SUB_YEAR>2 AND SUB_YEAR<=3;
          ELSIF(REC.SUB_YEAR>3) THEN
               UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION
               SET DISCOUNT = 25,p_amount= SUB_AMOUNT-SUB_AMOUNT*.25
               WHERE SUB_YEAR > 3
          ELSE
               UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION
               SET DISCOUNT = 0,p_amount = SUB_AMOUNT
               WHERE <condition>;
          END IF;
     END LOOP;
END;
```

Or you can done this with a simple `UPDATE` query,

```
UPDATE subscription 
set discount = CASE WHEN sub_year >1 and sub_year <= 2 THEN  10 
                    WHEN sub_year >2 and sub_year <= 3 THEN  20 
                    WHEN sub_year >3 THEN  25
               ELSE 0 END, 
    p_amount = CASE WHEN sub_year >1 and sub_year <= 2 THEN  SUB_AMOUNT-SUB_AMOUNT*.1 
                    WHEN sub_year >2 and sub_year <= 3 THEN  SUB_AMOUNT-SUB_AMOUNT*.2
                    WHEN sub_year >3 THEN  SUB_AMOUNT-SUB_AMOUNT*.25
               ELSE SUB_AMOUNT END;
```